# SoapClient class missing

Tags: php, soap

I need to use SoapClient class. Once I run a script that use it I get the following error:`Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/example/public_html/affiliate_script/acquireFeeds.php on line 11`

I have already asked my client to install it but he says it is impossible so far. Do you know any class that could be equivalent to the SoapClient and can be downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) which is a PHP-only solution that requires no extensions to be present (besides XML handling extensions I suppose).